# Passar parametros extras via gcm (google cloud message) - Cordova

Tags: java, android, apache-cordova, google-api

Ao enviar uma notificação para o `gcm`, adicionei um parâmetro na url chamado 'appUrl'. E preciso, ao abrir o meu app Cordova, passar esse parâmetro para o `index.html` para que eu possa redirecionar minha aplicação para o seu devidor lugar.

Porém, no caso abaixo sempre recebo `null`.
Se no `MainActivity`, eu passar o valor direto, sem intervenção de uma variável, funciona normalmente.

**GCMIntentService.java**

```
public void createNotification(Context context, Bundle extras)
{
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    String appName = getAppName(this);
    String appUrl = extras.getString("appUrl");

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, PushHandlerActivity.class);

    notificationIntent.putExtra("appUrl", appUrl);

    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("pushBundle", extras);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    int defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;

    if (extras.getString("defaults") != null) {
        try {
            defaults = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("defaults"));
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {}
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setDefaults(defaults)
            .setSmallIcon(context.getApplicationInfo().icon)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentTitle(extras.getString("title"))
            .setTicker(extras.getString("title"))
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String appUrl = extras.getString("appUrl");

    // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
    loadUrl(launchUrl + "?app_url=" + appUrl);
}
```

Comment: Você está enviando o parâmetro para a `Activity` correta? Pois no seu código está passando o parâmetro para `PushHandlerActivity` e não `MainActivity`.

Comment: Eu consigo enviar outro intent para o MainActivity? Acredito que removendo esse intent do PushHandler, as notificações não irão funcionar. Existe alguma outra forma de passar extras.getString("appUrl") para o MainActivity?

Comment: Pelo seu código entendi que você está enviando a informação de maneira correta, porém para o destino incorreto.

Comment: Você não está passando o "appUrl" para `MainActivity` por isso a `MainActivity` não recebe "appUrl".

Comment: Criei outro intent e mandei para o MainActivity e não consegui compilar o app. 'cannot find symbol MainActivity'... Desculpem se estou deixando passar algo simples. Engatinhando em java/android.  :/

Comment: Cara, aproveitando que você tá falando de GCM, ele garante fidelidade na entrega das mensagens? É em tempo real? e a ordem é preservada?

Comment: A ordem é preservada sim. E o tempo é muito bom. Resultado bem agradável.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente sobrescrever na sua Activity este Método:

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
```

Documentação:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)

Comment: Na MainActivity?

Comment: Isso!  na Activity que irá recepcionar o Bundle

Comment: Então seria dentro do onNewIntent que eu iria iniciar meu app com o loadUrl? É isso?

Comment: Após o onCreate, sobrescrevi o metodo: http://paste.ofcode.org/JcYvPybxk66nPnMNxzAKeK  . Mas agora não consigo compilar.

Comment: symbol:   class Intent
  location: class MainActivity
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

Comment: Você está compilando com qual versão do Android vc está compilando?

Comment: android 4.0.0.. Só pra reforçar.. Estou usando cordova, ok?

Comment: http://raphael-lemaire.com/phonegapjavadocs/com/phonegap/DroidGap.html#onNewIntent(Intent)

Comment: O que mandou Thiago, diz que tenho que sobrescrever.. Mas quando sobrescrevo, não consigo compilar minha app.

Comment: @RafaelSoufraz, poste o erro, talvez possa ajudar... tentei pesquisar algo específico, mas não encontrei nada! Abraços

Comment: Chegou a ver o código que postei no past.ofcode? É pra adicionar esse metodo no MainActivity? É isso?

Comment: Vi sim! um exemplo: https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent/blob/master/src/android/WebIntent.java